# JSON array in a jquery .each displays only last value of array when .append is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Array Table</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="" content="">
</head>
<body>

<table>
     <thead>
          <tr>
               
               <th>Details</th>
               <th>Data</th>
               
           </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">

//jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
function arrayprocess(){
  
  var display;
  
  var arrayobj = [{"name": "John","dept": "science","phone": "xxx-xxx-xxxx"}];
   
  jQuery.each(arrayobj, function(key, value){ 
   
   jQuery.each(value, function(label, answer){
    display = '<tr><td>'+label+ '</td><td>' +answer+'</td></tr>'});


  });
  $('#tbody').append(display);
  

}
arrayprocess();
//});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**
The JSON only array's last value is displayed. The rest of previous two values that is, `name:John` and `dept:science`...

**Present output:**

Details Data

phone   xxx-xxx-xxxx

**Expected Output**

Details Data

Name John

dept science

phone   xxx-xxx-xxxx

Comment: You need `display+=` to concatenate to the display variable.

Comment: awesome mplungjan! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your append statement needs to be inside the each function or else it will only append the last result, ex:

```
jQuery.each(arrayobj, function(key, value){ 

    jQuery.each(value, function(label, answer){
        display += '<tr><td>'+label+ '</td><td>' +answer+'</td></tr>';
    });
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan you are correct, i was just catching his mistake, edited my answer for the more efficient method

Comment: @BannedfromSO did you add the `$('#tbody').append(display);` after the outer each?

Comment: @Mauricio Tranjano - The `$('#tbody').append(display); ` won't work after the outer `.each`.

Comment: @BannedfromSO why not? it's still in the scope of the function

Comment: Try it yourself. I had tried it and it wasn't working. So I posted here.. `display +=` has to be included, without that the variable `display` couldn't able to collect all data but just the last value.